# Cannot serialize with scala-pickling because of OutOfMemory?

Tags: scala, scala-pickling

I am writing code for send object and data over the network using java.nio channel, and scala-pickling for serialization.
After many days debugging, I found some parts of my code generating OutOfMemory error in JVM. So what's wrong with scala-pickling? It cannot serialize?

```
val receivedRequestStr: String = new String(data)
val receivedRequest: Message = receivedRequestStr.unpickle[Message]
val responseRequest: Message = masterController handleRequest receivedRequest
val responseRequestPlk: JSONPickle = responseRequest.pickle
respond(key, responseRequestPlk.value.getBytes)
```

But I really don't know why, I even don't have any hint from sbt.
This is its error message

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.take(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:188)
        at sbt.Execute.next$1(Execute.scala:83)
        at sbt.Execute.processAll(Execute.scala:86)
        at sbt.Execute.runKeep(Execute.scala:66)
        at sbt.EvaluateTask$.liftedTree1$1(EvaluateTask.scala:342)
        at sbt.EvaluateTask$.run$1(EvaluateTask.scala:341)
        at sbt.EvaluateTask$.runTask(EvaluateTask.scala:361)
        at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$3.apply(Aggregation.scala:64)
        at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$3.apply(Aggregation.scala:62)
        at sbt.EvaluateTask$.withStreams(EvaluateTask.scala:293)
        at sbt.Aggregation$.timedRun(Aggregation.scala:62)
        at sbt.Aggregation$.runTasks(Aggregation.scala:71)
        at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$applyTasks$1.apply(Aggregation.scala:32)
        at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$applyTasks$1.apply(Aggregation.scala:31)
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:60)
        at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:60)
        at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$evaluatingParser$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Aggregation.scala:153)
        at sbt.Aggregation$$anonfun$evaluatingParser$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Aggregation.scala:152)
        at sbt.Act$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$actParser0$1$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$anonfun$$evaluate$1$1$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Act.scala:244)
        at sbt.Act$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$actParser0$1$$anonfun$sbt$Act$$anonfun$$evaluate$1$1$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Act.scala:241)
        at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:92)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
        at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:184)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:98)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:98)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:91)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:70)
        at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:65)
        at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:65)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:48)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:32)
        at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:24)
        at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:53)
        at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:28)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[error] java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

Comment: You are running this with `sbt run` right? Could you try packaging it up and running it outside of sbt?

Comment: I use sbt compile, but it stops